# Does the Border (Boundary) Points of a convex shape in the positive quadrant make a convex function?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be a convex body in 2-D with some non-zero intersection with positive quadrant and let it also contain origin. Let $c>0$ be the right-most point on the x-axis such that $(c,y)\in \mathbb{S}$ for some $y$. Define the function 
\begin{align}
f(x)=\max_{(x,y)~\in~\mathbb{S}}y ~~,x\in[0,c]
\end{align} 
Clearly, $f(x')$ is the northernmost point in the vertical strip $x=x'$, is $f(x)$ a convex function? (or concave).

eg::Think about a circular disk with center as origin or an ellipse with same center. Clearly, its border point's $y$ co-ordinate are a decreasing function in $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer is trivially positive. Let $x_1,x_2\in [0;c]$, $f(x_1)=y_1$, $f(x_2)=y_2$, $0\le\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$. Then $\lambda_1 x_1+\lambda_2 x_2\in [0,c]$. Since $\mathbb S$ is convex, $\lambda_1(x_1,y_1)+ \lambda_2(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb S$. Then $f(\lambda_1 x_1+\lambda_2 x_2)\ge \lambda_1 y_1+\lambda_2 y_2$.

But I remark, that the boundary of $\mathbb S$ in the positive quadrant may not be a graph of a function. E.g. think about a circular disk with center as (0,1) and radius 2.

Comment: +1 nice. Could you explain the last remark in more detail. Why can't it be a graph, $f(x')$ is the topmost point in the vertical strip $x=x'$ for all $x'\in [0,c]$. Thus, there should be a point corresponding to every point in x-axis. Isn't it?

Comment: The set of these topmost points not necessarily contains the whole boundary of $\mathbb S$ in the positive quadrant. For instance, in my disk example the vertical line $x=2-\varepsilon$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$ intersects the boundary of the disk in *two* points.

Comment: Hi, I request you to go through this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654817/convexity-of-a-complicated-function